# Selecting string of variable length from string

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to select a number from a string. The number can be between 5 and 10 characters long. For example, I have two job numbers to extract from a string.

```
"job number:45678 date:01/01/16"     # => jobnumber = "45678"
"job number:123421312 date:03/03/16" # => jobnumber = "123421312"
```

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? Some members may be working on answers and others may decide not to offer an answer because you have already selected one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looks like this just works:

```
"job number:45678 date:01/01/16"[/\d+/]
 => "45678" 

"job number:123421312 date:03/03/16"[/\d+/]
 => "123421312"
```

Comment: The number must have between 5 and 10 digits.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: Can you edit your post so I can remove my downvote?  One interpretation of the question makes your answer correct, and because the op accepted your answer, I'm inclined to believe that your interpretation of the question was correct.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

```
 r = /(?<=\Ajob number:)\d{5,10}(?!\d)/

"job number:45678 date:01/01/16"[r]
  #=> "45678" 
"job number:4567 date:01/01/16"[r]
  #=> nil 
"job number:0123456789 date:01/01/16"[r]
  #=> "0123456789" 
"job number:01234567891 date:01/01/16"[r]
  #=> nil
```

- `(?<=\Ajob number:)` is a *positive lookbehind* that requires the string 'job number:' to be at the beginning of the string (`\A`), but that string is not part of the match
- `\d{5,10}` matches 5-10 digits
- `(?!\d)` is a *negative lookahead* that ensures the match is not followed by a digit. Without this, my last example above would return `0123456789`.

Comment: I thought I'd test out my regex first, and confoundingly `String#[]` does not honor the x flag.  I can't remember running in to that before.

Comment: @7stud, idon't forget that `/...job number.../x` is converted to `/...jobnumber.../`. so you need `/...job\snumber.../x`.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'job number:45678 date:01/01/16'

regex = %r{
  \A               #Match start of string, followed by...
  job[ ]number:    #the literal string "job number:", followed by...
  (\d{5,10})       #a digit, 5 or more times--but not more than 10 times, captured in group 1.
}xm                #Flags: Ignore whitespace in regex. Dot matches \n.

puts str[regex, 1]  #Return group 1 of match.

--output:--
45678
```

Comment: If `str = 'job number:012345678988888888888888 date:01/01/16'`, `puts str[regex,1] #=> '0123456789'`. The string in the capture group cannot be followed by a digit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I know you put that restriction in your answer, but I didn't see where the op stated that restriction.  Although, it would be symmetrical to return nil for a number that is less than 5 digits as well as for a number that is more than 10 digits.  Another interpretation of the question: the numbers are always between 5-10 digits, so just return whatever is there--which would make the accepted answer correct.

Answer (score -2):

Found what i was looking for

/^[a-zA-Z]{5,10}$/

Comment: `^` and `$` mean beginning/ending of *line* in Ruby, not *string*, so they're almost always a mistake. You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead.